# ProcessBuilder not executing program correctly in java eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a program in ProcessBuilder in java. Below is the program. I have created the program in Eclipse IDE. While executing the program is showing errors.

```
//Demonstrate ProcessBuilder.
public class ProcessBuilder
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ProcessBuilder proc=new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe","testfile");
        try
        {
            proc.start();           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error executing notepad.");
        }

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "MyTest");
        try 
        {
            pb.start();
            System.out.println("Process has been started.");
        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

The system is displaying the constructor ProcessBuilder is undefined. I have java 7 installed, jre 1.7 installed. Still I am unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other suggested, the best option would be `rename` your class name, other option would be to

```
java.lang.ProcessBuilder proc=new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe","testfile");
```

and

```
java.lang.ProcessBuilder pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("java", "MyTest");
```

So you are explicitly telling your `javac` to use `ProcessBuilder` from `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 0):

You called your own class `ProcessBuilder`, so it hides the library class. Call your own class something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `ProcessBuilder` doesn't have a constructor `ProcessBuilder(String...command)`. My guess is that you wanted to write a demo for `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. Using the same name for the demo and the class which you try to use makes things confusing.

I suggest to rename your class to `ProcessBuilderDemo`. That will make `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` visible in the code.